# How do I correct this printing out copied files from directory in Unix Bourne Shell?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting, sh

So i need to write a Unix Bourne Shell to  to copy all the files from the directories named dir1 and dir2 into a new directory named dir3.

The script first copies all the files from dir1 into dir3.

The script then copies every file from dir2 to dir3 subject to these
conditions: if the file from dir2 is not already present in dir3, or if the dir2
file is newer than the same dir3 file it will overwrite its namesake in dir3.

These should be the output:

```
These files from dir1 copied into dir3:
a.c b.c file1.c
These new file(s) from dir2 copied into dir3:
file2.c
These file(s) from dir2 copied into dir3 and overwrite(s) their
namesakes in dir3:
a.c
```

```
$ ls
cp2.sh dir1 dir2 dir3
$ ls -l dir1
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 sxu staff 9 Aug 2 12:52 a.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 sxu staff 9 Aug 2 12:52 b.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 sxu staff 9 Aug 2 12:52 file1.c
$ ls -l dir2
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 sxu staff 9 Aug 2 12:53 a.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 sxu staff 9 Aug 2 12:51 b.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 sxu staff 9 Aug 2 12:53 file2.c
$ ls -l dir3
total 16
-rw-r--r-- 1 sxu staff 9 Aug 2 12:53 a.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 sxu staff 9 Aug 2 12:52 b.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 sxu staff 9 Aug 2 12:52 file1.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 sxu staff 9 Aug 2 12:53 file2.c
```

So technically because **dir2 a.c** is created 1 minute later than **dir1 a.c** so it gets pasted in to **dir3**, overwriting the previously pasted **dir1 a.c**.

This does not apply to **dir2 b.c** because it was created earlier than **dir1 b.c**.

However, my output is something like this:

```
These files from dir1 copied into dir3:
a.c b.c file1.c
These new file(s) from dir2 copied into dir3:
file2.c
These file(s) from dir2 copied into dir3 and overwrite(s) their
namesakes in dir3:
a.c
b.c
```

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/sh

#Test for directory existence
test -d $1
if [ $? -eq 1 ]
 then
 echo "'$1' directory does not exist."
 exit 0
elif
test -d $2
[ $? -eq 1 ]
 then
 echo  "'$2' directory does not exist."
 exit 0 
elif 
test -d $3
[ $? -eq 0 ]
 then
 echo "'$3' directory does not exist."
 exit 0
fi

#create dir3
mkdir $3

#output for users
echo "These new file(s) from $1 copied into $3:"
ls $1
ls $1 | while read file
do
 cp $1/$file $3/$file
done
echo "These new file(s) from $2 copied into $3:"
ls $2 | while read file
do
 test -f $3/$file
 if [ $? -eq 1 ]
  then
  echo "$file"
 fi
done
echo "These file(s) from $2 copied into $3 and overwrite(s) their namesakes in $3:"
ls $2 | while read file
do
 test -f $3/$file
 if [ $? -eq 0 ]
  then
  cp -u $2/$file $3/$file
  echo "$file"
 else
  cp  $2/$file $3/$file
 fi
done
```

These bits are wrong i suppose but cannot find out what is wrong...

```
echo "These file(s) from $2 copied into $3 and overwrite(s) their namesakes in $3:"
ls $2 | while read file
do
 test -f $3/$file
 if [ $? -eq 0 ]
  then
  cp -u $2/$file $3/$file
  echo "$file"
 else
  cp  $2/$file $3/$file
 fi
done
```

Thanks so much in advance. Much appreciated

Comment: Start by running your script through https://shellcheck.net

Comment: `elif 
test -d $3
[ $? -eq 0 ]` ?? Just `elif test -d $3; then`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a series of `elif`s, when a loop will do.  Only return an exit code of `0` when all is well, not when something goes wrong:

```
for d in "$1" "$2" ; do
    test -d "$d" || \
    { echo "'$d' directory does not exist."
      exit 1 ; }
done
```

And `mkdir` already will return an error if the destination directory exists, so there's no need to write redundant code.  This is enough:

```
mkdir "$3" || exit
```

Except for the output to the user, the file copy `while` loops aren't really needed.  Just use `cp` with the `-u` or `--update`, and `-v` or `--verbose`  switch; see `man cp` for details.  Both `while` loops can together be reduced to one line:

```
cp -uv "$1"/* "$2"/* "$3"
```

Comment: hi, do u mean the while loops for the "These new file(s) from $2 copied into $3:" or "These file(s) from $2 copied into $3 and overwrite(s) their namesakes in $3:"?

Comment: The combined file copying functions of both `while` loops in lines #29-32 and #43-53 can be duplicated with a single `cp` (see answer).